# ember concurrency, how to set timout value based on conditions

Tags: ember.js, concurrency, ember-concurrency

I am using ember-concurrency where I have to make API calls every 10 seconds and update the setup status for my application install phase. If there is an error, then I need the timeout value to be 1 seconds instead if default value of 10 seconds. Seems like every time timeout value is 10 seconds only and even with an error, user is on the screen for 10 seconds and then sees an error modal. Can anyone tell what can be a possible solution? or what I am doing wrong?

```
induceWait: task(function*() {
  while (continue) {
   // make the api call here
   //if error in any evaluating conditons, set timeout value to be 1 seconds, else 10 seconds
   this.get('store').findAll('status').then((response) => {
     if (response.flag) {
        this.set('timeout', 10000);
     } else {
        this.set('timeout', 1000);
      }
   }, (error) => {

   });
   yield timeout(this.get('timeout');
   this.get('induceWait').perform();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the root of the issue here is that the promise itself needs to be yielded.
So, what's happening currently is that the promise 'starts', and then you yield a timeout with whatever `timeout` is set to before your promise resolves.

in this example, I've used a local variable, and changed the name to `delayMs` to avoid a naming collision with the `timeout` function

```
induceWait: task(function*() {
  while (true) {

  let delayMs = 1000;

  const response = yield this.get('store').findAll('status');

  if (response.flag) {
    delayMs = 10000;
  } 

  yield timeout(delayMs);

  this.get('induceWait').perform();
}
```

Comment: @BhavyaBansal I just noticed something -- the while condition says `continue` did you mean for that to say `true`?

Comment: Hey yeah, continue means only till a condition satisfies and once I am done (like task is 100% complete), then I will get out of that while loop and stop invoking task.

Comment: so what's the reason to use that over while(true)?